# Using query_posts inside single.php loop

Tags: navigation, get-posts, globals

Inside of my loop in single.php, I used a custom query using `get_posts`  to return posts belonging to a certain category.

```
<?php                                                   global $post;
                                                        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                                                        $myposts = get_posts("paged=$paged&category=5");?>

<?php foreach($myposts as $post) :?>

<?php the_title();?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The problem is that the original loop, which is the single.php loop, seem to do not work after the execution of the query. For instance, the navigation links (next and previous) dont work.

Have you ever faced this issue? your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after your query to restore the global `$post` variable that the navigation link functions use to determine the next/previous posts.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).  Does about the same thing though, but for reference's sake:

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args =  array ( 'category' => 5, 'paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page'=> 5 );
$catPosts = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post' );

if( $catPosts->have_posts() ){ ?>
    <ul>

    <?php while ($catPosts->have_posts()) : $catPosts->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>
<?php 
} else {
    // no posts found
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thank you helgatheviking I agree with you and I really believe in the importance of reading about WP_Query vs get_posts. But I want to add that changing only this didnt resolve the problem. I was foregtting the wp_reset_query(); and that was the lacking function. have a good day.

Comment: Yes you were stomping on the global $post variable and not resetting it.  With `get_posts()` you need to `reset_post_data()` and with `new WP_Query()` you need to `wp_reset_query()`.  Glad you solved it! Cheers.

Comment: well explained. I add that `reset_post_data()` or as I did : `wp_reset_postdata()` both work with `get_posts()`. and with `new WP_Query()`, it is `wp_reset_query()`. I hope I used the exact words. Thank you

Comment: Yes it is supposed to be `wp_reset_postdata`.. that was a typo in my previous comment.

Comment: I think in both cases you need to just wp_reset_postdata. wp_reset_query restores the global $wp_query then calls wp_reset_postdata. if you don't touch the global $wp_query, then there's no query to reset. get_posts itself just creates a new WP_Query instance, so it stands to reason that if you don't need to reset the query with that, you also don't need to with a custom WP_Query.

Comment: Good point! I thought I remembered that once, but then saw it in the Codex again.  I've adjusted my answer for posterity. :)

Comment: now i have enough repu to vote helgatheviking and milo. many thanks